# Unable to edit concrete5 Blocks on my localhost

Tags: block, concrete5

the problem is that the blocs are editable once the website is online **on server**,but on my localhost i can't edit them the blocks are visible but i can't click on them?the same code is on loalhost and on server.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

- This could happen because of a JavaScript error. Did you check the developer tools console?
- I'd also recommend to clear the concrete5 cache when you copy a site from one server to another
- I'd also recommend to disable pretty URLs (http://documentation.concrete5.org/editors/dashboard/system-and-maintenance/seo-and-statistics/pretty-urls)

Comment: Why disable pretty-urls?

Comment: Because I came across a lot of people who don't have mod_rewrite configured and if you move a site you end up having a few issues. I know this doesn't apply to people like you, but in general you have less problems if you disable them first.

Comment: It'd be better to do this with environment configuration rather than diverging the localhost code and the production code.